# Skip some columns when doing a select

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building an ajax web application and i am displaying a chain select in jquery that does some selecting behind the scenes and saves me lots of time writing new routes and views.However,i would like to know if there is a way i could reduce my work further by not writing new models.

I have this `controller`

```
<?php
class Tools extends CI_Controller {

    public function message($to = 'World')
    {
        echo "Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
    }
    public function boom(){
    echo "boom".PHP_EOL;
    }
    public function q(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = ? AND member_club_id = ? AND membership_year = ?";

    $count = $this->db->query($sql, array(null, 1, null));
    foreach ($count->result() as $row)
    {
    echo $row->member_name . PHP_EOL; 
    }
    }
}
?>
```

which is an attempt to skip some column and display some other.

This is its sql equivalent

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = null AND member_club_id = 1 AND membership_year = null;
```

They both don't display anything.Is there a way i can skip a column of my choosing?.

Comment: It's not really clear, by "skipping column" what do you mean? Change `SELECT *` for `SELECT column1, column2` ?

Comment: SELECT thiscolumn,thatcolumn FROM table;

Comment: Just say the column names instead of the * and it will work.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue I mean to totally ignore the column even if its written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is truly bizarre or not

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = (select member_id) AND member_club_id = 1 AND membership_year = (select membership_year);
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = (select member_id) AND member_club_id = (select member_club_id=1) AND membership_year = (select membership_year);
```

Both queries work.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set which columns are returned like this

```
SELECT id, member_name FROM members WHERE member_id = null AND member_club_id = 1 AND membership_year = null;
```

If you actually mean 'skip rows' you can use `LIMIT`

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = null AND member_club_id = 1 AND membership_year = null LIMIT 5, 5;
```

This will return all columns for rows 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10

Comment: Zero rows returned in `SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = null AND member_club_id = 1 AND membership_year = null LIMIT 5, 5;`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to skip columns in the where part of the statement?

The reason your query is not returning any rows is because anything, when compared to null, will evaluate to false:

- column = null is false whatever the value of column
- column <> null is also false whatever the value of the column

If you really don't want to modify the query generation, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM members 
WHERE (? is null OR member_id = ?) 
  AND (? is null OR member_club_id = ?) 
  AND (? is null OR membership_year = ?)
```

However I do not recomend this, because the database engine will have trouble in identifying a good index to solve the query with a statement like this. My preferred solution would be to dinamically generate the SQL based on the arguments that are received. The conditions would be inserted only if the value is not null.